# Problem with Log4j2 Configurator initialize in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, log4j2

I'm working on a spring boot project, which use log4j2 for logging. The log4j2.xml is stored in DB, so I have to retrieve it before using.
It looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <!-- setting -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="merchantdb">/syslog/translog/merchantdb/</Property>
        <Property name="pattern1">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}[%5p][%C{2}][%t] %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="pattern2">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}[%5p][%C{2}.%M()] %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>
    <!-- appender setting -->
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern1}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="merchantdb" filePattern="${merchantdb}/merchantdb.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern1}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="merchantdb_io" filePattern="${merchantdb}/merchantdb_io.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="merchantdb_i" filePattern="${merchantdb}/merchantdb_i.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="merchantdb_o" filePattern="${merchantdb}/merchantdb_o.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="rmds" filePattern="${merchantdb}/rmds.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern2}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
            </Policies>
            <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy/>
        </RollingFile>
        <Socket name="socket" host="10.77.249.230" port="20002" reconnectionDelay="5000" immediateFlush="true">
            <JsonLayout compact="true" includeStacktrace="true" charset="UTF-8" eventEol="true" locationInfo="true" objectMessageAsJsonObject="true" stacktraceAsString="true">
                <KeyValuePair key="hostName" value="$${hostName}"/>
            </JsonLayout>
        </Socket>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="merchantdb" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="merchantdb"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="merchantdb_io" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="merchantdb_io"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="merchantdb_i" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="merchantdb_i"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="merchantdb_o" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="merchantdb_o"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="socket"/>
        </Logger>
        <Logger name="com.alibaba.druid.pool" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="rmds"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I know there are multiple ways to initialize *.xml. It did work when using URI to initialize. However, I found myself having problem with initialize with ConfigurationSource. It seems the config doesn't set properly when using ConfigurationSource, logger still print in default format.
Below is my code, is there anything that I miss?
Thanks a lot.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigLoader {
    public static Logger logger;
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("ds_settingsDB")
    public Logger log4j2() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("loading Log4j2");
        FileWriter fw = null;
        LoggerContext context = null;
        try {
            String fieldvalue = SettingsDB.get("Log4J2.xml");
            
            //initBySource(fieldvalue); //this doesn't works
           
            initByFilePath(fieldvalue); //this works
            logger = LogManager.getFormatterLogger("merchantdb");
            logger.info("log4j2 load complete");
            return logger;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            throw new EipException(e);
        } finally {
            if(fw!=null){
                fw.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private LoggerContext initBySource(String fieldvalue) throws Exception {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fieldvalue.getBytes("utf-8"));
        ConfigurationSource source = new ConfigurationSource(in);
        LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(null, source);
        return ctx;
    }

    private LoggerContext initByFilePath(String fieldvalue) throws Exception {
        FileWriter fw = null;
        LoggerContext ctx = null;
        String filePath = "C:\\apconf\\log4j2zzz.xml";
        fw = new FileWriter(filePath);
        fw.write(fieldvalue);
        fw.flush();
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if(file.exists()){
            ctx = Configurator.initialize(null, filePath);
        }
        return ctx;
    }

}
```

Comment: By the time control reaches your code Spring Boot has reconfigured Log4j2 twice. Try `Configurator.reconfigure` instead of `initialize`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I've tried both initialize & reconfigure. The thing is, when using URI(or ConfigLocation), both initialize(name, ConfigLocation) & reconfigure(URI) could work. But when using  ConfigurationSource, initialize(loader(null), ConfigurationSource) wouldn't. And this is what I wanna find out. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Try the `ConfigurationSource(Source source, final byte[] data, long lastModified)` constructor and provide a `source` parameter with an URI (e.g. `dummy:myConfig`). Consider submitting a bug on the [Log4j2 JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/).